# Reading from offset in stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I need to split a header and payload that I've read into a stringstream.

I've found the position of the start of the payload in the stringstream.

can read the header with:

```
// where ss is the source stringstream
ssHeader.read(ss.str(), nDataStartPos-1);
```

Now I'd like to read the remainder into a payload stringstream.

```
ssPayload.read(ss.str()+nDataStartPos, nTotalBytesRed);
```

This fails with the following errors:

- error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
- initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]'

I'm guessing that the str() command returns a temporary, constructed from the internal buffers of the stringstream.

So I guess I could copy the ssPayload to a string, then do an substr, but is there a more efficient way to achieve this, or maybe stringstream is the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: stringstream probably is the wrong tool for the job.  Where does the data originally come from, before the first time it ends up in a stringstream?

Comment: You seem to be using [the `read` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) wrong. The object you call read on (`ssHeader` and `ssPayload` in your example) is the *source* stream, the stream you read *from*. The argument is the destination, where the `read` function will write its data.

Comment: data comes from an async read from boost asio socket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guess correctly, and yes a stringstream is the wrong tool for the job.

Generally we read into a fixed buffer, repeatedly copying its contents into whatever you want until everything's been read.

And yes that kind of sucks.

You may be able to use stream iterators and `std::copy`.

Answer (score 1):

If the data (header and payload) is text, then use plain `std::string` and use [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the header and payload.

If the data is binary, then you might use `std::vector<uint8_t>` (or `std::vector<int8_t>`) and extract data using e.g. [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n). But if the data is binary, why not simple use packed structures that contain the exact data needed, including the header (possibly use two structures, one for the header and one for the payload)?